# Data Sharing in Geoserver

Tags: geoserver

What are all the folders I have to share with others who would like to use my data ? 
I gave workspaces and styles folder. But it is not working in Geoserver 2.4.4. Since layergroup is inside the workspace I ignored the layergroup folder

[image]

Comment: Ok, hopefully this will help you. After setting up geoserver you are not sharing through your file system and permissions on your folders should not come into play.Geoserver allows you to set up services such as WMS that can be accessible to others. If you want others to add data set up styles etc that can be done through the Geoserver interface. Geoserver gives you a security system to set up users and permissions. Whatdo you want others to be able to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data may be used by anyone who has the credentials to access the base URL of gesoerver.

If you want instead to allow access of geoserver_data_dir to the other users (such as other GeoServer with the web.xml file set properly), you should share the entire directory.

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/datadirectory/data-dir-setting.html#data-dir-setting